SQL Server slows every night
The last couple of nights i woke up to websites with very slow loads due to SQL Server issues. The issue resolves on server restart
I tried sp_BlitzFirst and got "High Percentage Of Runnable Queries"
Where can i see which queryes are actually running


Where can i see which queryes are actually running

You would have to catch them in the act with some sort of trace.
If you don't have a formal monitoring tool (e.g. SQL Sentry), you can use sp_WhoIsActive to tell you what's currently running, how long it's been running for, what it's currently waiting on, what process is blocking it (if any), among other helpful information.
In the past, as a "poor man's monitoring tool", I've scheduled a SQL Agent Job to run this at a frequent interval and log the results to a table. If you know roughly when this issue starts, you can do the same for just that timeframe, and then you'd be able to review the results after the fact. Or if you want to see it in real-time, you can just run it adhoc as needed.
Alternatively, SQL Server also offers other ways of tracing what's running via Extended Events and the Profiler. The former takes a little more effort setting up correctly, and digesting the results, if you're not familiar with them. The latter is much easier to get started with but some people have concerns of being resource heavy on the server, and there's no automated way to log the results. Though I personally don't think it's a problem if you filter appropriately and only run your session for the minimal necessary time. I've never experienced an issue.

A footnote, it is possible to get SQL Profiler data stored as a file, and then load that data into a table for review... but it's a long, awkward, and difficult process. It all starts with sp_trace_create, read/google that and go from there. (My limited understanding is that SQL Profiler is merely a GUI for this trace functionality.)

Extended Events. Friends don't let friends use Profiler/Trace in 2024 on new versions of SQL Server. But yeah, total agreement. To see what was running in detail versus pulling stuff from the cache, which may or may not have what you need, setting up data collection is the way to go.

@PhilipKelley actually you can save the results of a Profiler trace directly from the UI into a table on SQL Server. That's a very simple process.

@GrantFritchey Eh, if it's good enough for Paul White, it's good enough for me.

@J.D., True, but then you have to have SQL Profiler running, either on the server or on a workstation attached to the server, and that can get problematic. I've used SQL Agent to start a trace at a targeted time (e.g. 2:00 am) for a set period (e.g. for the period of suspect recurring activity), and retrieved the log file next morning for analysis. Awkward, fussy to set up, but very effective. (And, yes, Extended Events is probably better, but Trace still works, so...)

@PhilipKelley the Profiler gui actually uses a different caching mechanism when it's attached to a server and, yeah, can in fact cause issues. That's completely independent from Trace, which doesn't do what the Profiler gui does.
